# Use an option button group named "status" to control if the buttons are empty

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub Übernehmenbutton_Click()

Dim ctrl As Control
Dim emptyField As Boolean

    
emptyField = False


For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf ctrl Is ComboBox Or ctrl.Name = "AufgabeText" Then
                If Trim(ctrl.Value) = "" Then
                emptyField = True
                ctrl.SetFocus
                ctrl.BackColor = vbYellow
                MsgBox "Please fill in the required field.", vbExclamation, "Missing Value"
                Exit For
            Else
                ctrl.BackColor = vbWhite
            End If
        End If
    Next ctrl
    
If emptyField = False Then
'if there are no emptyfield
    
Dim last As Integer
       
last = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

'Business A & B gewählt
ActiveSheet.Cells(last, 3).Value = Business.Value

        
'Die Dateien von Status übernehmen
If Offen = True Then
    ActiveSheet.Cells(last, 5).Value = Offen.Caption
ElseIf Erledigt = True Then
    ActiveSheet.Cells(last, 5).Value = Erledigt.Caption
ElseIf Warte = True Then
    ActiveSheet.Cells(last, 5).Value = Warte.Caption
ElseIf Begonnen = True Then
    ActiveSheet.Cells(last, 5).Value = Begonnen.Caption
End If


'Aufgabe Text in zellen übernehmen

ActiveSheet.Cells(last, 2).Value = AufgabeText
     
'Echtzeit übernehmen
 ActiveSheet.Cells(last, 1) = Now
 
 'Fälligskeit datum
 ActiveSheet.Cells(last, 4) = Tag1.Value & "" & Monat1.Value & "" & Jahr1.Value
 
 
With Range("A2:E" & last).Borders
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Weight = xlThin
End With


With Range("A2:E" & last).Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Weight = xlThick
End With

With Range("A2:E" & last).Borders(xlEdgeTop)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Weight = xlThick
End With
    
With Range("A2:E" & last).Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Weight = xlThick
End With

With Range("A2:E" & last).Borders(xlEdgeRight)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Weight = xlThick
End With
Unload UserForm1
    End If

 
End Sub
```

**The code first initializes some variables and sets the value of emptyField to False. It then loops through all the controls in the user form, checking if they are either a ComboBox or have the name "AufgabeText". If a control is found to be empty, it sets the emptyField variable to True, sets the focus on the control, changes its background color to yellow, displays a message box prompting the user to fill in the required field, and exits the loop.

If there are no empty fields, the code then retrieves the last row of data on the active sheet and adds a new row below it. It populates various cells in the new row with data from the user form, including the value of the "Business" ComboBox, the "Offen", "Erledigt", "Warte", or "Begonnen" status, the "AufgabeText" field, the current date and time, and the due date.

The code also sets various cell borders to make the data easier to read, and then unloads the user form.Now I am also  trying to implement an option button group to validate if a set of buttons are not selected. The name of the option button group is 'status'. I have searched for solutions but have been unable to find a way to control the buttons in a group. Can anyone provide guidance on how to achieve this?

You can see the design of my userform here:

[image: Userform1]

Comment: What what does an "empty button" should mean?

Comment: I meant "not selected "in userform.

Comment: Do you mean checked **Option** buttons? If they are in a group, shouldn't only one have a 'True' value? Do you want identifying which of them is checked? If not, please better explain what you have and what you try doing, please. Do you know their `groupName`?

Comment: i would like to check if at least one of the option button is selected.So that user can not unload the form without selecting at least one of the option buttons .For now i was able to do this   for comboboxes and textbox but couldnt find any solution for option buttons from one group.Gropu name is "status".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, use the next function:

```
Function isOptBChecked(grp As String) As Boolean
   Dim ctrl As MSForms.Control
    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(ctrl) = "OptionButton" Then
            If ctrl.groupName = grp And ctrl.Value = True Then
                isOptBChecked = True: Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

It should be called (from a button, or from an event) in the next way:

```
    Const groupName As String = "status"
    If Not isOptBChecked(groupName) Then
        MsgBox "There must be one checked Option  button in group " & groupName, vbCritical, _
               "One checked Option button needed"
    Else
        'do what you need...
    End If
```